# Invalid hook call error in React App after re-installing node modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My app was working fine then I made a build for testing so it gave

```
Error: Minified React error #321;
```

but it was working fine on localhost, so I tried to investigate the problem and after a while I did `yarn install` then `yarn start` so it crashed as shown below everytime I navigate to a screen that has this line

```
  let { path } = useRouteMatch();
```

I didn't install anything new and it was working fine before I removed then re-installed the node modules

Nothing worked with me and it's driving me insane

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

[image]

Comment: Well it's issue #1 or #3 in the message.  I would delete node_modules and let package.json reinstall everything.  Make sure that package.json doesn't have anything uneccessary.  Let packages load in their own dependecies.

Comment: That's what I did but nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the answer was simply remove the ^ symbol in react, react-router and react-router-dom versions in package.json then delete node_modules and ran npm install again and everything back to normal